# Heroku Sinatra Site Suddenly Down

Tags: mongodb, heroku, sinatra

Trying to get a beat on why my Heroku site won't load as I haven't touched in 6 months+

http://t2bthr.herokuapp.com

Below are the logs. Can anyone shed some light into this? I see this error:

```
/app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:130:in `issue_authentication': Failed to authenticate user 'heroku' on db 'app476164' (Mongo::AuthenticationError)
```

I'm just not sure why all the sudden I'd be having authentication issues.

```
2014-05-29T00:17:43.330292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2014-05-29T00:17:43.330293+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T00:17:43.330298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T00:17:41.551293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 23291 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2014-05-29T00:17:44.952612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-29T00:17:44.979544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-29T00:55:00.607805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=a9823832-62fb-461c-a284-49968b44850e fwd="186.210.151.58" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T01:03:17.147588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-29T01:03:19.495911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 7390 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2014-05-29T01:03:22.751972+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329833+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:111:in `authenticate'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329806+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:130:in `issue_authentication': Failed to authenticate user 'heroku' on db 'app476164' (Mongo::AuthenticationError)
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:15
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329970+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329854+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/../lib/db.rb:10:in `init_mongo'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329914+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:14
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329952+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329933+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329894+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1222:in `configure'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.329989+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330081+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330118+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330063+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330136+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330191+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330155+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330211+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330248+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2014-05-29T01:03:23.330230+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2014-05-29T01:03:24.749727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-29T01:03:24.741605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-29T01:24:47.714571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=037cebb1-d9eb-450e-97f1-e3846121d2b9 fwd="204.155.149.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T01:31:12.690405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=776fe43b-c755-47e7-b741-5a2ff59b1ee8 fwd="91.200.12.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T01:31:13.714036+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/wp-login.php host=2bthr.com request_id=66ac2b17-b220-448a-ad98-d684bbdba67c fwd="91.200.12.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T01:54:42.347628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=6d6e97c9-467d-4598-a590-b9c595cc9204 fwd="198.204.249.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T02:25:42.894295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-29T02:25:45.238484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 27261 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2014-05-29T02:25:49.223844+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446648+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:130:in `issue_authentication': Failed to authenticate user 'heroku' on db 'app476164' (Mongo::AuthenticationError)
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:111:in `authenticate'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446656+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/../lib/db.rb:10:in `init_mongo'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446670+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446658+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:15
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446659+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1222:in `configure'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446669+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446672+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446675+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446676+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446678+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446683+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:14
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446681+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446754+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446686+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446691+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T02:25:49.446692+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T02:25:50.718902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-29T02:25:50.711009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-29T05:06:51.450635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-05-29T05:06:54.632367+00:00 app[web.1]: Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/../lib/db.rb:10:in `init_mongo'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:15
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918751+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:111:in `authenticate'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918791+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/sinatra-1.2.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1222:in `configure'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918736+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.gems/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/../lib/mongo/db.rb:130:in `issue_authentication': Failed to authenticate user 'heroku' on db 'app476164' (Mongo::AuthenticationError)
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from ./bthr/app.rb:14
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918802+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918808+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918811+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918814+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918810+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918815+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2014-05-29T05:06:54.918812+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/.gems/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2014-05-29T05:06:56.095995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-05-29T05:06:53.328857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 58046 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2014-05-29T05:06:56.090088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-05-29T05:28:10.046206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/?author=1 host=2bthr.com request_id=5792f655-69f8-4b48-860a-8780a01db388 fwd="94.102.53.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T09:55:11.507149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=170b4b0b-f566-4c5e-be01-f19c8f50cd85 fwd="105.237.54.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T09:55:14.043513+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=2bthr.com request_id=fb065a48-8adf-4516-8313-67d50be49e11 fwd="105.237.54.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T09:56:43.107933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=dc3f3987-2caa-4b73-80b8-062d2ace6fa5 fwd="150.70.97.119" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T10:06:23.161084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path=/ host=2bthr.com request_id=7acf11a7-27f9-42ed-81ec-12d6a488b936 fwd="119.63.193.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-05-29T10:21:06.786562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/robots.txt host=www.2bthr.com request_id=0fcd52e8-98f6-426c-bf9a-8600159d5976 fwd="65.55.52.111" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Are you correctly using the MONGOHQ_URL config variable in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the MongoLab add-on (https://addons.heroku.com/mongolab), they recently announced that on May 22 and May 23, they would be resetting everyone's login credentials in response to the Heartbleed bug.

If you were not using the MONGOLAB_URI environment variable to connect to your database, but instead hard-coded your login URI, then your app would error out.  To fix this, update your username and password.  To prevent future errors like this in the future, create an additional database user and use that username and password wherever you use a hard-coded login.

Here is a post that describes some of the steps MongoLab has taken to address the issue:
http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/04/heartbleed-security-update/